# NHibernate DistinctRootEntity Transformer For Sub-Collection

Tags: nhibernate

I have a collection of Root Entities (`IList<RootEntity>`) that is returned from an NHibernate call using the ICriteria API. `RootEntity` has a collection of child entities, lets call that `IList<Child1Entity>`. `Child1Entity` has a collection of child entities (`IList<Child2Entity>`), which, being the third layer, causes the `Child1Entity` collection to have duplicates.

My question is how can I apply the de-duplication process to the child collection.

The reason I have duplicates is because I am using LeftOuterJoin on the child collections. I cannot remove the LeftOuterJoin.

Each of the sub-tables are joined using the following code:

```
ICriteria rootCriteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(RootEntity));

rootCriteria.CreateCriteria("Child1Collection", "Child1CollectionAlias", NHibername.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

rootCriteria.CreateCriteria("Child1CollectionAlias.Child2Collection", "Child2CollectionAlias", NHibername.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

rootCriteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Child2CollectionAlias.Property", value));

rootCriteria.SetResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntity);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code? You shouldn't have any duplication in the child collection, unless there's something else you are not telling us.

Comment: Updated my question. There is another layer of children that I forgot to mention in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up writing an in-memory filter for child collections. NHibernate does not currently support the functionality I was looking for.

Thanks for looking.